# Python - how to store many classes with out using too much memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a class to store some different types of values, and I got a bunch number of these classes. How can I store them neatly without using too much memory? Or is there a way of not using this stupid class?

```
class item:
    id = int()
    time = float()
    flag = int()
    description =str()

    def __init__(self, id, time, flag, description):
        self.id = id
        self.time = time
        self.flag = flag
        self.description = description


dataBaseSize = 134217728

dataList = list()

for i in range(dataBaseSize):
    new = item(i, 0, 0, "i")
    dataList.append(new)
```

Doing something like this would cause the memory to explode. So How can I optimize this in Python?

Comment: The solution is to use a database. Python is distributed with sqlite. In memory, you could *at best* with a structured array you could hope to get something like(8+8+8+10)*134217728*1e-9 ~=4.6 gigabytes for something of that size, assuming you are working with 1-bytes per char strings and limiting yourself to 10 characters. Just use a data-base. Don't re-invent the wheel badly

Comment: Note, there is no point in using those class variables, you always use instance variables there. You may not be familiar with Python classes...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know this requires a lot of memory, using 7 gigabytes or so is ok for me, but when I doing this allocation, it consumes memory till 24 gigabytes and more! So is there a structure like `struct` in C or should I just using  instance variables instead?

Comment: Why not just use a database? You can use `ctypes` for structured tightly packed types, but this is unweidly. Python objects are quite memory intesive compared to C-structs. An *empty* python object would require something like 70 bytes

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's troublesome for me, I am not building a database here, just evaluate some ideas, actually this is used to monitor memory pages, code is written in C, but python is easy to use and evaluate.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see, so I think I'd better build up a numpy array to store my values separately.

Comment: you can use a structured array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `__slots__` [trick](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/__slots__magic.html).

There will be a significant difference in memory usage(40 to 50%).

```
class MyClass(object):
    __slots__ = ['name', 'identifier']
    def __init__(self, name, identifier):
        self.name = name
        self.identifier = identifier
```

Comment: thanks! your trick is useful, however, I discarded class and used numpy array to store my data instead.

Comment: @JiangFeng, you may also want to check pandas, which uses numpy in a more convenient way.